# magento 2 disable custom cron job from module

Tags: magento2

I have created a **Custom cron job** for **product price** updation using **csv**. I want to disable **cron job** if **Module is disabled from admin**. How it will be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the status of the module in your cron observer file. If it is disabled status, then simply skip the cron process.

I dont think there is a way to disable a cron through the XML configuration.

Comment: Yes that is, but there will be in system log that the cron is running ?

Comment: If it's not possible with XML then I have to keep in method only.

Comment: Not sure system log will get updated when a cron ran unless you have enabled it

Answer (score 1):

To stop cronjob when module disabled from admin configration you can add check module is enabled in configration or not.

You can use below mentioned check for it.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Cronmethods
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ){
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;;
    }
    public function method(){
        if($this->isModuleEnabled()){
            $this->logger->info('Cron running'); //You can check these logs in var/log/system.log
            //Your logic
        }
    }
    public function isModuleEnabled(){
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('sectionid/groupid/fieldid', $storeScope);
        //Note: replace sectionid, groupid and fieldid matching with your system.xml enabled select box. 
    }
}
```